# How to ensure in Confluence only users from certain IP can access and others hit the login page to access?

Tags: jira, confluence, bitbucket-server

I have Confluence set up in Azure Data-centre and running ok.
I want to make sure

- Users in certain IP range can access Confluence pages.
- Users that are not in above IP range will see the login page. And, once logged in can use the Confluence.

Now, I suppose if I add in the **server.xml** the following line (src:https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-allow-only-certain-ip-addresses-to-have-access-to-confluence-658015747.html)

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1,192.168.0.1,192.168.50.*" />
```

as below:

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
    <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <Connector
                port="8080"
                connectionTimeout="60000"
                disableUploadTimeout="true"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="16384"
                redirectPort="8443"
                maxThreads="280"
                minSpareThreads="280"
                enableLookups="false"
                acceptCount="10"
                debug="0"
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                proxyName="confluence.mydomain.com.au"
                proxyPort="443"
                scheme="https"
                secure="false"
        />

        <Engine name="ConfluenceDC" defaultHost="localhost" debug="0">

            <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" startStopThreads="4">
                <Context path="" docBase="../confluence" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <Manager pathname=""/>
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="60"/>
                </Context>

                <Context path="/synchrony-proxy" docBase="../synchrony-proxy" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="60"/>
                </Context>

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1,192.168.0.1,192.168.50.*" />

            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

This possibly will allow the Confluence to be accessible by the IPs given. But I want to ensure other IP hit the login page for accessing. How to do that?

Comment: What you have here is for allowing or disallowing general access based on the IP address only. You want more than that, or rather something different - you want free access to the documents when the request comes from a specific IP, and otherwise require a login first. Not sure if anything exists to facilitate that, it seems to be a rather specific use case.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was wondering if I can write somekind of rewrite based on "not ip -> then go to page1 or else just allow"?

Comment: It will be easier for you to do this in proxy server like nginx server. Not sure if tomcat server provide this flexibility. https://www.nginx.com/

Comment: nginx will provide url rewrites based on conditions.

Comment: see this as well for nginx: https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page

Comment: This info could be helpful: we had similar setup done by confluence admin; If I try to hit confluence from Office network, it won't ask for any password, I will be inside system, able traverse & edit pages based on my privileges. But same I do from home then it will ask for credentials first. I have heard in conversations that they have used some technique called white-listing of IP addresses, I'm not sure how to achieve that, but I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: I guess, this is what admins were using: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Whitelist-IP-address-Can-we-provide-access-to-only-specific-IP/qaq-p/769802